# Designing UI container in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to create components like these within the body of an ASP.NET page. My page has many of these. What control to use for this? Should I create some custom container.  I am new to ASP.NET.
The header and content should be able to have Image backgrounds.

EDIT: I am using WebForms.

[image]

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: If you are using MVC then that should be a partial view.  Easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need it to do. You can use a web user control if this is what you're looking for:

```
<uc1:MyUserControl ID="UserControl1" HeaderText="Foo" Content="Bar" ... />
```

If you're looking for the content section to act as a template, then a custom server control inheriting from `TemplateControl` is more along the lines of what you need.

You need a custom server control if this is what you're looking for:

```
<cc1:MyCustomControl ID="MyCustomControl" HeaderText="Foo">
    <Content>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
    </Content>
</cc1:MyCustomControl>
```